# Getting an SQLite working within Android and accessing data

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to get an SQLite database to work in Android and have a few questions!

I have put the following in the `onCreate` method of my database class, which extends `SQLiteOpenHelper`.

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `challenge` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, `date` TEXT )");
```

I then have the following method.

```
public void addChallenge(){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    Date cDate = new Date();
    String fDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(cDate);

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("date", fDate);

    db.insert("challenge", null, values);

}
```

And the following would grab the challenge added above back.

```
public int getChallengeId(){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    Date cDate = new Date();
    String fDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(cDate);

    String countQuery = "SELECT id FROM challenge WHERE date = " + fDate;

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);

    int challenge_id = 0;

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        challenge_id = cursor.getInt(0);
    }

    return challenge_id;

}
```

My issue is that the challenge ID is returning as 0.

So I have a few questions.

- Where is the database stored by default within Android?
- Am I calling this correctly?

The code I use to access the above methods is as follows

```
Database db_add = new Database(context);
db_add.addChallenge();
db_add.close();

Database db_get = new Database(context);
challenge_id = db_get.getChallengeId();
db_get.close();
```

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: I cannot see your problem right now, but I advice you to use an ORM mapping library instead of working with plain SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL query is not correct.

`2015-02-23` tells the database that you want to subtract the numbers `2` and `23` from the number `2015`.

Strings must be `'quoted'`.
However, you should avoid such formatting problem by using parameters:

```java
String countQuery = "SELECT id FROM challenge WHERE date = ?";
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, new String[]{ fDate });
```

Comment: That seems to have fixed the issue! I assumed the database wasn't being created. Could you give me a pointer to where the database is stored? It would be nice to be able to get hold of it and open it up!